# How to negate the definition of continuity using Generalized De Morgan's Law.

Tags: real-analysis, logic

The difinition of the Continuity is the following.

$f(x)$ is continuous at a point $a$ means for every $\epsilon > 0$ , we will get a $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x) - f(a) < \epsilon|$ for all $x$ satisfying $|x - a| < \delta .$

By using quantifiers , we can write $(\forall \epsilon > 0) (\exists \delta > 0 ) [ \forall x ( |x- a | < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(a) | < \epsilon )]$

The negation of the above statement will be '$( \exists \epsilon > 0) ( \forall \delta > 0 ) [\exists c (|c - a | < \delta \implies |f(c) - f(a)  | \geq \epsilon )]$ .'

But I want to know how to do that using generalized De morgan's Law. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Why [Generalized DeMorgan's Laws](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1542248/generalized-demorgans-law-proof) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The negation of the statement $A\implies B$ is not $A\implies \neg B$. The negation of the statement $A\implies B$ is, in fact, $A\land \neg B$. This can easily be seen if you rewrite $A\implies B$ as $\neg A\lor B$ (that's the definition of implication), then applying De Morgan's law.

Therefore, your solution is incorrect.

Comment: I did not understand your solution. What are A and B ? Why my solution is incorrect ? Please clearly mention.

Comment: Please read the whole expression. You might have missed the first two quantifiers in negated statement.

Comment: @sani For any expression $A$ and $B$, the expression $\neg(A\implies B)$ is equivalent to $\neg A\land B$, and **not** $A\implies \neg B$. Therefore, when negating the expression $|x-a|<\delta\implies|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$, the negation of this expression is **not** $|x-a|<\delta\implies|f(x)-f(a)|\geq\epsilon$.

Comment: @sani Also, why did you invert two of your quantifiers, but not the third?

Comment: Instead of this ---$\exists  \varepsilon > 0 \ \ \  \ \forall \delta > 0 \ \ \ \ \exists x\in D  \ \ \ \left( |x-x_0|< \delta \wedge |f(x)-f(x_0)|\geq\varepsilon \right)$ , can I write -- $\exists  \varepsilon > 0 \ \ \  \ \forall \delta > 0 \ \ \ \ \exists x\in D  \ \ \ \left( |x-x_0|< \delta \implies|f(x)-f(x_0)|\geq\varepsilon \right)$ @5xum

Comment: Can you please answer my query? I am waiting. I am really confused if these two statements are equivalent or not. @5xum

Comment: @sani  I already told you. No, the statement $A\implies \neg B$ is **not** equivalent to $A\land \neg B$. That's still true no matter how many quantifiers you put in front of it.